# Default keying: How to require password?

Tags: password, default, keyrings

Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit

I always had to enter password for default keyring, immediately after logging in.

Just noticed that the popup asking for password doesn't popup any more.

How do I go back to having a password for the default keyring?

Answer (score 0):

The default keyring does not pop up if you leave it password-less. It will pop up ONCE after installing Ubuntu and if you do not enter a password it will stay quiet.

Open "keyrings" from Dash and it will show this when there is no password:

[image]

Rightclick "login" and set a password when this shows:

[image]

After that you will need to provide a password. Remove the password with the same method to clear it again.

Comment: Like I said, I ALWAYS had a password for the keyring and never disabled it. Missing now. In keyring, under Password, have two entries: Login and Default. Both have the open padlock symbol. I changed passwords for both Login and Default and still had the open padlock symbol. Right-clicked and hit lock and now they have closed padlock symbol. Will let you know what happens after I login.

Comment: Changed passwords for both Login and Default--still no popup for password.